# Prefect not finding .env file

Tags: dotenv, prefect

While running a prefect flow from **Pycharm** everything works fine but when I start it from **Prefect Server**, the flow doesn't find the .env file with my credentials and fails with my own assertion error from this code:

```
class MyDotenv:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dotenv_file = ".\\04_keep_local\\.env"
        assert os.path.isfile(dotenv_file), "\n-> Could't locate .env file!"
        dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)
```

I've used these commands on my virtual environment (venv) to start the server and the agent:

```
prefect backend server
prefect server start
prefect agent local start
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Deleted the images and the containers from Docker and restarted all of them. It worked but I don't know what happened...

Answer (score 4):

Did you perhaps start your `LocalAgent` in a directory that doesn't contain your .env file?
The `LocalAgent` runs a flow as a subprocess of itself. Meaning the directory your flow runs in is the directory you executed `prefect agent local start`